# Can not import Class from a gradle Dependency

Tags: java, swing, kotlin

In my kotlin project I have added the following dependency to my build.gradle file (im using gradle as build management system).

```
implementation group: 'com.formdev', name: 'flatlaf', version: '0.43'
```

Now I want to use the FlatLightLaf`Class, but I cant import it. The flat look and feel is a java swing based look and feel. According to the developer from the laf, it should work in a kotlin based project as well. Important is, that kotlin is able to use swing.

The following image shows my project hirachie.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnMSo.png)

Comment: Have you reloaded the build.gradle file in IntelliJ? On the bottom bar, there is a Gradle bar. If you open it, you can click on reload or something.

Comment: Solved it. Thank you :)